# Android how to delete an object

Tags: java, android, gps, garbage-collection, finalize

So im making an app where an arrow points towards a certain geo location point. In my program every time the phone moves a new instance of the GPSTracker class is called. The problem arises when after 10seconds of running the app freezes. I need to somehow discard gpsTracker right before a new gpsTracker is created. `

```
@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    GPSTracker gpsTracker =  gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);
    float azimuth = event.values[0];
    Float TrueNorth, theta, beta, aplha;
    Location curloc = new Location("Current Location");
    Location destloc = new Location("Destination Location");
    Float f = 0.000621371F;
    curloc.setLatitude(gpsTracker.getLatitude());
    curloc.setLongitude(gpsTracker.getLongitude());
    destloc.setLatitude(47.66432);
    destloc.setLongitude(-122.08458);

     Float h = getMiles(curloc, destloc);
     Double g = Double.valueOf(h);
    tvHeading.setText(g.toString() + " Miles");
    GeomagneticField geoField = new GeomagneticField(Double
        .valueOf(curloc.getLatitude()).floatValue(), Double
        .valueOf(curloc.getLongitude()).floatValue(), Double
        .valueOf(curloc.getAltitude()).floatValue(),
            System.currentTimeMillis());

    azimuth -= geoField.getDeclination();
    float bearTo = curloc.bearingTo(destloc);

    if(bearTo <0){
        bearTo = bearTo + 360;
    }

    float direction = bearTo - azimuth;

    if(direction <0){
        direction = direction + 360;
    }

    RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(
            currentDegree, -direction, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f
    );
    ra.setDuration(210);
    ra.setFillAfter(true);
    Image.startAnimation(ra);
    currentDegree = direction;

    if(curloc == destloc){
        tvHeading.setText("Arrived At Destination!");
    }

}
```

` As you can see from the code, GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this) is created. Like previously stated, the app freezes because it seems as if the object isnt being discarded right away.

Comment: So only create one instance as a class member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use singleton concept here, if this object exist then don't create otherwise create it.

```
GPSTracker gpsTracker;

public GPSTracker getGPSTrackerInstance() {

    if(gpsTracker == null) 
        gpsTracker = new GPSTracker();

    return gpsTracker;
}
```

This method will create `GPSTracker` class object if object of it doesn't exist otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to explicity remove an object from memory, you wanna do:

```
gpsTracker.finalize();
gpsTracker = null;
System.gc();
```

Try this. This should work.

Comment: i tried to use your method however setting the object to finalize gives me an error